# How to apply a binary function in Matlab on two vectors to get a matrix of all pairwise results?

Tags: matlab

Is there any function in Matlab that can take two vectors (not necessarily of the same size) and apply a binary function on every pair of the vector's elements resulting in a matrix n1xn2, where n1 and n2 are the lengths of the input vectors?

Something similar to pdist2, but with arbitrary function pointer instead of the distance function.

```
Example usage:
v1 = [1, 2, 3]
v2 = [2, 3]

Apply(@plus, v1, v2) -> [3, 4; 4, 5; 5, 6];
```

Note: although, the example is numerical, the actual vectors I need to work with are arrays of cells each containing a string (all strings have equal length). The binary function takes two strings and returns a scalar, for example - strcmp.

Comment: The answer I posted works on the example data. It's not really clear how you want to add the strings. Could you provide an example? What do you want if `v1 = {'one', 'two'}` and `v2 = {'the', 'cat', 'dog'}`?

Comment: Updated the question. The function receives two strings and returns a scalar, think - strcmp, strcat ...

Comment: Still unclear to me... Please provide an example with strings.

Comment: `v1 = [{'one'}, {'two'}]; v2 = [{'two'}, {'three'}]`. Apply(@strcmp, v1, v2) -> `[0, 0; 1, 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with `ndgrid` and `arrayfun`. Consider the following example data (cell arrays of strings):

```
v1 = {'aa','bb','cc'};
v2 = {'1','22'};
```

and example function (string concatenation):

```
fun = @(str1, str2) [str1 str2]
```

Then:

```
M = length(v1);
N = length(v2);
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:M, 1:N);
reshape(arrayfun(@(k) fun(v1{ii(k)},v2{jj(k)}) , 1:M*N, 'uni', false), M,N)
```

gives the desired result:

```
ans = 

    'aa1'    'aa22'
    'bb1'    'bb22'
    'cc1'    'cc22'
```

In the general case, simply define `v1`, `v2` and `fun` as needed.

Comment: This seems to work, but the `arrayfun` is extremely slow. Not sure it's any faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: It's not faster than a `for`, actually. You could easily replace it by a `for`. I think it's difficult to avoid the `accumarray`/`for` for arbitrary functions. Perhaps for your specific function it could be vectorized. Tell us what the function is...

Comment: After converting my function, so that it could work with matrix inputs instead of string inputs, I've passed to it `repmat`-ed input vectors. The problem is that the new function is more complicated/less readable than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

This one works on the example data:

```
repmat(v2,numel(v1),1)+[v1(:), v1(:)]

ans =
     3     4
     4     5
     5     6
```

## Update

Try something like this if `numel(v2) ~= 2` (still only for the numerical example you have provided):

```
repmat(v2,numel(v1),1)+repmat(v1(:),1,numel(v2))
```

Comment: It also assumes that v2 has exactly two elements.

Comment: In the numerical case it's easier to `bsxfun(@plus, v1', v2)`.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the OP's last comment (very different from the content of the question) would be the following:

```
>> v1 = [{'one'}, {'two'}]; v2 = [{'two'}, {'three'}];
>> cellfun(@strcmp,repmat(v1',1,size(v2,2)),repmat(v2,size(v1,2),1))

ans =

     0     0
     1     0
```

For the example numeric data and the plus operation in the question, that is solved by:

```
>> v1 = [1, 2, 3]; v2 = [2, 3];
>> bsxfun(@plus,v1',v2)

ans =

     3     4
     4     5
     5     6
```

However, I think the answer to the string concatenation problem is answered well by Luis Mendo.

In general, to do an operation for all pairs, `bsxfun` should be your go-to function for numeric arrays.  For cells, strings, and other non-POD types, consider combinations of `repmat`, `arrayfun` and `cellfun`.  It's hard to be more specific without a more specific question.