# All possible combinations of strings MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, permutation

UPD: I wish to say sorry to the StackOverflow community for asking a question without making effort to solve the problem by myself. From now on, I'll ask questions only if I really have serious problem

I am now developing the program that generates all the possible permutations of string elements:

I started with:

```
A = ['Bridge','No Bridge'];
B = ['Asphalt','Concrete','Combined'];
C = ['Fly Ash',' Sulphur','Nothing'];
D = ['Two lanes','Four lanes with barriers'];
E = ['Paid','Non-paid'];
F = ['Mobile','Non-mobile'];
N = length(A)*length(B)*length(C)*length(D)*length(E)*length(F);
out = zeros(N,6);
```

But now I'm stuck with what to do next. The output needed is something like:

```
out = 

    'Bridge' 'Asphalt' 'Fly Ash' 'Two lanes' 'Paid' 'Mobile'
    'Bridge' 'Asphalt' 'Fly Ash' 'Two lanes' 'Paid' 'Non-mobile'
    'Bridge' 'Asphalt' 'Fly Ash' 'Two lanes' 'Non-paid' 'Mobile'
    'Bridge' 'Asphalt' 'Fly Ash' 'Two lanes' 'Non-paid' 'Non-mobile' etc
```

Please, could you suggest the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it is not a code writing service but aims to help you get your programs working. Please show what code you have written to try and solve the problem and explain what parts are not working. Please also look at the **Help** link at the top of the page and the sections on how to write good questions.

Comment: You can get some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19875203) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors) (work with the indices, and then use them to index the strings)

Comment: For a Python implementation, see the itertools product recipe http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that in Matlab, the following square bracket notation: `['Hello', 'World']`, does not in fact create an array of string, but concatenates the strings "Hello" and "World" to yield 'HelloWorld'. So, in this case, you should use [Cell Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) instead: `A = {'Hello', 'World'}` (note the curly brackets).

To answer your question:
 Although you could go for something more generic (which you should in real-life code), for now, since you know the arrays of hand, you can simply create nested `for` loops like this:

```
A = {'Bridge','No Bridge'};
B = {'Asphalt','Concrete','Combined'};
...    
for aIndex = 1:length(A)
    for bIndex = 1:length(B)
        % add more loop levels here
        fprintf([A{aIndex}, ',', B{bIndex}, '\n']);
    end
end
```

With ouput:

> Bridge,Asphalt
>   Bridge,Concrete
>   Bridge,Combined
>   No Bridge,Asphalt
>   No Bridge,Concrete
>   No Bridge,Combined

Comment: For *n* input cell arrays, *n* nested for loops are required. This solution isn't generalizable.

Comment: @IceArdor - I'm aware of that. That is why I wrote: "Although you could go for something more generic (which you should in real-life code)". I still think, however, that this straight-forward approach is better for beginners. Usually, one should write some annoying loops in order to realize why a generic solution is superior :).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate all combinations of the indices, and then use those indices to build the result from the strings:

```
A = {'Bridge','No Bridge'};
B = {'Asphalt','Concrete','Combined'};
C = {'Fly Ash',' Sulphur','Nothing'};
D = {'Two lanes','Four lanes with barriers'};
E = {'Paid','Non-paid'};
F = {'Mobile','Non-mobile'}; %// data. Cell arrays of strings

[a b c d e f] = ndgrid(1:numel(A),1:numel(B),1:numel(C),1:numel(D),1:numel(E),1:numel(F));
out = [A(a(:)).' B(b(:)).' C(c(:)).' D(d(:)).' E(e(:)).' F(f(:)).'];
```

Or, if you need the results in the order of your example:

```
[f e d c b a] = ndgrid(1:numel(F),1:numel(E),1:numel(D),1:numel(C),1:numel(B),1:numel(A));
out = [A(a(:)).' B(b(:)).' C(c(:)).' D(d(:)).' E(e(:)).' F(f(:)).'];
```

This gives

```
out = 

    'Bridge'       'Asphalt'     'Fly Ash'     'Two lanes'    'Paid'        'Mobile'    
    'Bridge'       'Asphalt'     'Fly Ash'     'Two lanes'    'Paid'        'Non-mobile'
    'Bridge'       'Asphalt'     'Fly Ash'     'Two lanes'    'Non-paid'    'Mobile'    
    'Bridge'       'Asphalt'     'Fly Ash'     'Two lanes'    'Non-paid'    'Non-mobile'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not the case in the question asked, but if A, B, C, D, E and F were two element cell arrays, then we could use few dirty tricks -

```
num1 = (num2str(111111+str2num(dec2bin(0:63))) - '0')';
comp1 = cell(size(num1,2),6);
for k = 1:size(num1,2)
    comp1(k,:) = [A(num1(1,k)) B(num1(2,k)) C(num1(3,k)) D(num1(4,k)) E(num1(5,k)) F(num1(6,k))];
end
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it works only if each cell array has two possible values, which is not the case

Comment: Damn I didn't see that there are three ones too! Thanks for pointing that to me.