# How can I generate all possible strings of length n with say k different characters (in lexicographic order)? (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab

I have the letters "A", "B", "C", "D", and "E" and I want to generate all possible strings of length 7 with these letters (redundancy allowed). So, I would like to get:

AAAAAAA

AAAAAAB

AAAAAAC

AAAAAAD

AAAAAAE

...

So on and so forth with all possible strings. I know how to do this manually via the following, create:

A = ['A'], B = ['B'], etc...then create embedded for loops to concatenate all elements. However, I would like to just feed in a generic list of ABCDE in a function, and just feed the function an integer to get a variable result. How could I do this?

Comment: Maybe Luis' answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329725/all-possible-combinations-of-strings-matlab) question will help. I think.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Thank you for your reply. While this Luis' answer and that question are very good references, the implementation does not allow for indexed repeats, such as "bridgebridgebridge".

Comment: Apply [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922) with input `vectors = repmat({'ABCDE'},1,7);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Test = 'ABCDE'; 
A  = cell(7, 1);    %//pre-allocating for speed
[A{:}] = ndgrid(Test);  
y = cellfun(@(Test) {Test(:)} , A);
y = horzcat (y{:}); 

>>  
AAAAAAA
BAAAAAA
CAAAAAA
DAAAAAA
```

EDIT: ops... didn't see the 7..